# after footer collapse, vertical alignment of btn and text problems

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a responsive footer with bootstrap 3.0.3.
(http://bootply.com/100613)

in mobile view, vertical alignment of left-side a lind and "pull-right"ed btn and text is different.
I do style='vertical-align:top;' in "a btn", but it make only text move up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the vertical-align property (or leave it as `vertical-align: middle`) and add:

```
display:inline;
```

Comment: great! it works. display:inline is a magic keyword for alignment issues.

Comment: @OpenCode - If this works for you, then please mark this as answer by pressing the 'check' button. :)